# WP e-commerce: getting products by SKU

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm working on a site that uses the WP e-commerce plugin (Gold version) and I need to display a list of products that match a list of SKUs.  Users fill in a form, and a list of product SKUs is generated depending on their answers.  I need to create a page that fetches these products and displays them, preferably in the default grid view/list view style.

Any ideas how to do this?  Looking through the documentation, I was expecting a "get_products()" function that could take the SKU as an argument, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that.  How could I go about doing this?

Thanks a lot,

Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP E-commerce uses WordPress post objects to store products, so you don't need any special functions or callbacks. [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) will support everything you need, you can learn about the details of how everything is set up by reading about their [database schema](http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/database-schema/).

Specifically, the SKU is in the `wp_postmeta` table with a `meta_key` of `_wpsc_sku`.